# what device is larger than "computer" in semantic ui?

Tags: semantic-ui

Using Semantic UI 2.4 from

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css

I find semantic ui easy to pick up but I haven't found a list of "devices" yet, I show `mobile`, `tablet`, and `computer` from some searching, but there must be something bigger than a "computer" because

```html
<div class="ui padded grid">
    <div class="mobile only row">
        <div class="red column">mobile: Maecenas malesuada dui eu interdum </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tablet only row">
        <div class="orange column">tablet: Maecenas malesuada dui eu interdum </div>
    </div>
    <div class="computer only row">
        <div class="green column">computer: Maecenas malesuada dui eu interdum </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

all three divs disappear if the viewport is wider than `1199px`.  Where can you find a list of device classes?

Answer (score 0):

OK found it in the code, it is `large screen` - interesting 'tis two words but that's the idea behind semantic anyway.

Found it using the CDN code and seeing where "computer only" and "tablet only" were located
[image]